# Найти строки где разница с предыдущим элементом меньше N

Tags: python, запрос, pandas, filter, dataframe

Необходимо выбрать все строки, где разность значений ячеек одного столбца меньше 5.
Пробовал с помощью  `df.query((C - C) < 5)`, но это не верно.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ получить данные строки?

Comment: что значит разность ячеек одного столбца? Приведите небольшой воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы хотите получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: df.query сравнивает разные колонки каждой строчки. А не одну и ту же колонку в разных строчках.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [20]: np.random.seed(1)

In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10)*20, columns=['C'])

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
           C
0   8.340440
1  14.406490
2   0.002287
3   6.046651
4   2.935118
5   1.846772
6   3.725204
7   6.911215
8   7.935349
9  10.776335

In [23]: df['C'].diff()
Out[23]:
0          NaN
1     6.066050
2   -14.404202
3     6.044364
4    -3.111534
5    -1.088346
6     1.878432
7     3.186010
8     1.024135
9     2.840985
Name: C, dtype: float64

In [24]: df['C'].diff() < 5
Out[24]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
Name: C, dtype: bool

In [25]: df[df['C'].diff() < 5]
Out[25]:
           C
2   0.002287
4   2.935118
5   1.846772
6   3.725204
7   6.911215
8   7.935349
9  10.776335
```

Comment: Да, именно это я и пытался сделать, спасибо!

Comment: @Wittgenstein, на `stackoverflow` существует отличная возможность сказать спасибо: [вариант 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814), [вариант 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) ;)

Comment: @Wittgenstein [на русском справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)